# while loop does not honor loop condition

Tags: bash, shell

While Loop does not stop even after the condition `-ge` is not satisfied

```
$ cat looptest.sh
#!/bin/bash

function looptest()
{
    max=5
    while [ $max -ge 0 ]
    echo $max
    do
        max=`expr $max - 1`
    done
}

looptest
```

Am i missing anything here ?

Thanks

Comment: `(( max++ ))` or `max=$(( max + 1 ))`. No need to ever use `expr` in bash (or sh for that matter).

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies two instances of legacy/antiquated (1980s) syntax in the code.  One possible  modern (Bash) way to do it is `for ((max=5; max>=0; max--)); do echo "$max"; done`.

Comment: And `local max=5` to avoid making it a global variable visible outside the function. Speaking of functions, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#function_foo.28.29

Answer (score 6):

The command is interpreted as:

```
while condition; do commands; done
```

In your case the condition is:

```
[ $max -ge 0 ]
    echo $max
```

Or more compact:

```
[ $max -ge 0 ]; echo $max
```

Since `echo` returns a successful status code, then the loop will never terminate, you should move the `echo` statement inside the `do ... done` block.

```
    while [ $max -ge 0 ]
    do
        echo $max
        max=`expr $max - 1`
    done
```